# Editing TeXnicCenter source code for {align}

Tags: equations, texniccenter

Is there a simple way to change the TeXnicCenter source code so that the equation array button pops out:-

```
 \begin{align*}
 \end{align*}
```

instead of

```
 \begin{align}
 \end{align}
```

Only I find I supress more equation numbers than I include by far, in my assignments.

Comment: Maybe this would be better off on Stack Overflow, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option to make your TeXnicCenter autocomplete when you start writing `align*` and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd>. So maybe it's better than using a mouse click.

First if you go to your folder shown below, you'll find a lot of xml files and some toolbar icon pictures.

[image]

These XML files hold the auto-complete keywords by scanning your input. You can include your own stuff in them by editing these files but if you include too many of them it will just get slower and slower since as the number of possibilities increase so is the time to scan for them.

So if you open the file `base.xml` you'll see lots of stuff that are being tracked while you type. Note that if you feel that `math.xml` is a better place to put this then you can use that file it doesn't matter. And we just add the `align*` environment as shown

[image]

I've used Notepad++ but that's not important, the important thing is that it's running on that *Run as administrator* rubbish otherwise it won't allow you to save the modified file.

After saving the file and opening TXC, if we start typing `align*`, we have

[image]

after using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

For the TikZers you see that `TikZ.xml` file right? you are welcome :)

Comment: It should be noticed, that such changes will be lost on an update or re-installation of TeXnicCenter.

Comment: @Speravir Indeed. It's important to have a backup.